# Updating to Angular 7 - error with @angular/animation

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

When I run *ng update @angular/core*, I get the following error:

```
Package "@angular/animation" has an incompatible peer dependency to 
"@angular/core" (requires "4.0.0-beta.8" (extended), would install "7.0.0").
```

I was able to run `ng update @angular/cli` with no problem

I already ran `npm update`

Here are my ng versions:

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.2
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.2
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.2
@angular/animation                4.0.0-beta.8
@angular/cdk                      6.4.7
@angular/cli                      7.0.2
@angular/material                 6.4.7
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.2
@schematics/angular               7.0.2
@schematics/update                0.10.2
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.19.1
```

Comment: try `ng update @angular/core --force`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would do the trick:

To Forcefully update add a **`--force`** flag.

```
ng update @angular/core --force
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already run `npm update` I will try the `--force` flag